# preventDefault not working in all browsers/devices

Tags: jquery, preventdefault, sidr

I am using the [sidr menu](https://www.berriart.com/sidr/) for a website. I added a simple function to toggle the hidden submenus. I don't know why but i am not able to get it work in all browsers. The first solution is working in Firefox, edge and Safari, but not in Chrome, the second Solution is working on Chrome but not Firefox....

```js
$('.sidr ul li.sidr-class-page_item_has_children > a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle("slow");
});

$('.sidr ul li.sidr-class-page_item_has_children > a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: By not working you mean it follows the `a href` target instead of showing the `ul` ?

Comment: There must be an underlying problem as the internal logic of `on('click')` and `click()` is identical. I would suspect there's an issue with the event bubbling through the DOM to be caught somewhere else, but with such a small example of the problem we can't really diagnose any issues for certain.